# Time complexity of modular arithmetic

Tags: math, matlab, time-complexity

Say I wanted to calculate a (mod n). What is the time complexity of this? I'm using Matlab, and am not sure how Matlab calculates it. Does it divide a by n, subtract the integer part, and then multiply by n?

Does it make sense to ask 'what is the time complexity of this'?

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to ask about the time complexity for long numbers `a` and/or `n`. The related field is called Computational Number Theory. For example, see this [book](http://shoup.net/ntb/).

The usual integer arithmetic, which most likely is used by Matlab, is an ALU operation (or multiple operations) performed in a constant time. In this case, one has to remember that the size of the integer is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the built in help Matlab calculates `MOD(x,y)` as:

`MOD(x,y) = x - floor(x./y).*y`

where the floor function rounds towards minus infinity (that is strips the decimal part).

Runtime will be constant as long as you don't calculate `mod(X, y)`
where X is a vector, in that case it will scale linearly with the number of elements in the vector